# Value is not showing into alert box from Servlet Ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsp, servlets

I am retrieving some value from servlet into jsp page using ajax button click event.Here event response is coming success in firebug but values from server side is not showing in the alert box here is my code..

JSP.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
       var calltype;
   $('#scalltype').click(function(evt){
     evt.preventDefault();
     $.ajax({
     url: "Calltype",              
     type: "GET", 
     success: function(data){
     calltype=data;
     alert(calltype);
  },
  error:function(){
      console.log("AJAX request was a failure");
  }   
});});
```

And here is my servlet code

```
ArrayList calltype = new ArrayList();
               while(rs.next()){
                   String toc=rs.getString("calltype");
                   calltype.add(toc);
                }

            out.print(calltype);
            System.out.println(calltype);
            out.close();
```

Comment: check in  console.log(calltype);

Comment: @Riturajratan in console.log values are coming but its not coming into alertbox why?

Comment: @Riturajratan sir if i want to use these values can i use from calltype variable

Comment: see update and check @vikas

Comment: @PeterRader but Calltype is servlet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check in `console.log(calltype);`

**because in alert object not appear so use in console :)**

update

if i want to use these values then you use from calltype variable like

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
       var calltype;
   $('#scalltype').click(function(evt){
     evt.preventDefault();
     $.ajax({
     url: "Calltype",              
     type: "GET", 
     success: function(data){
     calltype=data;
     console.log(calltype);
    callbackfunction(calltype); //use in this your callback

  },
  error:function(){
      console.log("AJAX request was a failure");
  }   
});});
```